# Loading a URLBookmark with security scope in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

In a sandboxed app, I am using `NSOpenPanel` to get the user to select a source folder. I then save a bookmark to reuse next time the app loads like this:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let bookmark = try! url.bookmarkData(options: .securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess)
defaults.set(bookmark, forKey: "sourceFolder")
```

Then `onAppear`:

```
if let bookmarkData = defaults.data(forKey: "sourceFolder") {
print(bookmarkData) // 808 bytes
var stale = false
let savedCurrentDirectory = try! URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &stale)
```

But this fails with:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."

If I remove the `.withSecurityScope` it seems to work fine. What's going on?

Comment: Same thing happened to me. Did you ever figure out why this was happening? (Thank you for posting this. Your fix of removing .withSecurityScope saved me.)